# When to call the gang of four? [When to use design patterns?]

Tags: refactoring, software-design, design-patterns

In [The Guerilla Guide to Interviewing](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/GuerrillaInterviewing3.html) Joel says that guys who want to get things done, but are not smart will do stupid things like using a visitor design pattern where a simple array would be sufficient.

I find it hard to detect, if the design pattern suggested by the [Gang of Four](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gang_of_Four_(software)) should be applied.

Therefore, I would like some examples from Your work experience

- When is a simple approach (fixed size array) sufficient?
- What is the minimum size of a piece of software that justifies the use of the GoF patterns?
- When to refactor from simple-minded to GoF? Can this be done in a sensible way?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I often find that using test driven development helps guide me when faced with these questions.

- *When is a simple approach
  sufficient?*  It is always sufficient
  to use the simplest approach to get
  the next test to pass.  But knowing
  when/how to refactor is the real art
  form.
- *What is the minimum size of a
  piece of software that justifies the
  use of the GoF patterns?*  A rule of
  thumb I once read is that when you
  code something once, fine, when you
  duplicate that code somewhere a
  second time, make a note and move
  on.  When you find a need for the
  same code a third time, it's time to
  refactor to remove duplication and
  simplify, and often that involves
  moving to a design pattern.
- *When to
  refactor from simple-minded to GoF?* 
  I like what @anopres said - it's
  time when you feel the pain of not
  having the design pattern in place. 
  The pain (or code "smell") may
  manifest itself in several ways. 
  Code duplication is the most
  obvious.  Refactoring books like
  Fowler's [Refactoring](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201485672) or
  Kerievsky's [Refactoring to
  Patterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321213351) list many such pain
  points/code stenches.
- *Can this
  [refactoring] be done in a sensible
  way?*  The trick to refactoring is to
  have a suite of unit tests in place
  which you have confidence in, and
  then to refactor without causing any
  of those tests to fail. 
  Refactoring, by definition, does not
  change the functionality of your
  code.  Therefore, if your tests
  continue to pass, you can have a
  pretty good feeling that you didn't
  break anything.  Although it can be difficult, I actually enjoy this part of TDD, it's almost like a game to make changes without breaking any tests.

In summary, I would say that TDD helps guide me to write the code that is sufficient at the time, and perhaps more importantly helps me to make the changes later when inevitably requirements change, more functionality is required, etc.

Answer (score 12):

Design Patterns are a consequence, not an objective. You don't think *today I shall use Strategy Patterns*, you just do it. Halfway through doing the third nearly identical class you stop and use a paper notebook to figure out the general case and knock up a base class that describes the shared context. You refactor the first two classes to be descendants, and this gives you a reality check and quite a few changes to your base class. Then the next thirty are a walk in the park.

It's only the next day at the team meeting that you save everyone thirty minutes of boredom by saying "I used strategy pattern. They all work the same so there's only one test program, it takes parameters to change the test case."

Intimate familiarity with patterns makes you use them reflexively, whenever the situation demands it. When people treat the use of patterns as an objective in its own right, you get stilted, ugly code that speaks of mechanism rather than purpose; the how rather than the why.

---

Most patterns address recurring fundamental problems like complexity mitigation and the need to provide extensibility points. Providing extensibility points when its clear they won't be needed pointlessly complicates your code and creates more failure points and test cases. Unless you're building a framework for release into the wild, solve only the problems you actually face.

Comment: Simple explanation of the Strategy Pattern!

Answer (score 11):

Patterns are only tools and vocabulary. You write the code to be as simple, understandable and maintainable as you know how. By knowing patterns you have more allternatives at your disposal, and you have a language to discuss pros and cons of the approach before implementing it.

In either case you dont just "switch" to "using a pattern". You just keep doing what you allways do, write the code the best way you know how.

Answer (score 7):

This is similar to any other design decision.  Ultimately, it depends.  You should learn those patterns that are useful in your language (many GoF patterns aren't needed in Lisp or Smalltalk, for example), learn their advantages and disadvantages, understand the constraints of your system, and make the choice that best fits your needs.

The best advice that I can give is to learn, learn, learn.

Comment: Not many released products were built with Lisp or Smalltalk, and I think that's probably because while C is low level, it can implement high level designs with judicious use of patterns. So your tools are as high or as low level as the situation requires. The flip side of this is the demands this places on developer comprehension and skill. And yes, I've been thinking about your answer for seven years. :)

Comment: I think not many products use Lisp or Smalltalk because when the microcomputer revolution happened, the number of programmers exploded, and only low level languages were practical on the early microcomputers.  Therefore, the new programmers were all used to low level languages, even after microcomputers could do more.  It took thirty years for the microcomputer programming culture to almost catch up to Lisp and Smalltalk with languages like Perl, Python, Ruby, and JavaScript.  To be fair, I say this as someone who's written more production code in C than in Lisp and Smalltalk combined.

Comment: Also, C is spectacularly well designed. Function pointers in data structures can provide much of Object Oriented Programming. I've believe the Unix device driver system, with major device numbers selecting a driver (set of procedures) and minor device numbers selecting a device (a particular collection of state) is an early example of Object Oriented Programming. Drivers are classes and devices are objects. This is achieved by storing function pointers in structures. I'm honored that you found my post so thought provoking!

Answer (score 3):

Switching from a simple approach to a formal design pattern is usually something that happens fairly naturally for me as a problem increases in complexity. The key is to be familiar enough with the patterns that you can recognize the tipping point and switch from the simple approach to a design pattern when it will bring the most benefit for current and future development.

For a larger, more complex project, the tipping point should be fairly early on; in many cases, before you even start coding. For smaller projects, you can afford to wait before deciding to implement a pattern.

One of the best things you can do to increase your ability to recognize when a pattern should be used is to take some time after completing a project to examine how complex your "simple" approach has become. If it would have taken you less time and effort to implement a pattern, or if the pattern would clarify what you were trying to do, you can file that knowledge away for the next time you encounter a similar problem.

Answer (score 2):

When you have a problem that one of the patterns solves.  The GoF book has a section in each chapter that explains what types of scenarios each pattern is appropriate for.  You should *not* analyze each problem you have, then go look up what pattern to use.  You should become familiar with the patterns so that you learn to recognize what situations call for them.

Answer (score 0):

One of the nice things about the the original GoF book is that there is discussion of the scenarios where the pattern would best solve problem.  Reviewing these discussions can help you determine if "it's time".

Another good place to start is with Head First Design Patterns.  The exercises that illustrate the use of different design patterns are elaborate enough to offer a good learning experience.  In addition the exercises are also grounded in real world scenarios, so it's never a stretch to see when the appropriate times to apply design patterns.